# draw a book in photoshop

Tags: adobe-photoshop

I want to create a front view [x -y plain view] of a book for library software.

Here is an example of what I am trying to design (front view of this book cover).

[image]

I tried it myself and this is the result:

[image]

But I was not able to achieve the same look for the down curve effect (The Spine & Hindge, see red marking on the yellow book mockup). My attempt doesn't look that great. My question is how can I create that kind of down curve using Photoshop?

Here is a current screenshot of the book mockup in use.

[image: Here is a current screenshot of the book mockup in use]

Answer (score 1):

I would do it using gradients.  I'm only picturing the small section you need help with and these are just some quick settings to get you started.  You will need to play with them to get the right look.

1. Create a gradient for the shadow:

[image]

2. Create another gradient for the highlight:

[image]

I didn't adjust the gradient sizes, positions, or opacities.  Those are all things you will want to play with on your own, but this is at least where I would start.

**To show you a little more detailed version of what I mean, since you commented about it looking wrong.**

[image]

Comment: thanks but isn't this look like upper curve i want down curve style

Comment: @FastSnail I didn't play with the gradients...adjust their sizes to get it to look how you want.  I was just pointing you in the direction that I would go.  I'm adding another image to the answer to show you how it looks much different, when placed in context and edited a little more.

Comment: @FastSnail wait...are you having trouble with the spine cover or the joint?  I was showing you how to create the joint, but I would also use a gradient to create the spine cover as well.

Comment: i'm sorry if question is unclear are you sure you focus on red marked down curve .plz look at this image http://i.imgur.com/1Rs0KAa.png .i want that red mark part not green marked convex part

Comment: i'm following this way now